# Writing new identical rows out of a quantity column

Tags: r

I will explain my problem with an example, we have the following data file in R:

```
Species   Diameter    Height   Amount

Oak       1           4        2

Beech     2           12       3

Maple     1.5         7.5      1

Oak       2           9        2
```

So we have 4 columns (`Species`, `Diameter`, `Height` and `Amount`) and several rows with data. Im trying to write a code to transform the data above to this type:

```
Species   Diameter    Height   
Oak       1           4  

Oak       1           4

Beech     2           12  

Beech     2           12 

Beech     2           12 

Maple     1.5         7.5   

Oak       2           9   

Oak       2           9
```

So the column `Amount` is now gone but we obtained several identical rows equal to the initial value in the column `Amount`.

I have a problem implementing this as a code (I am quite new to R programming). I am thinking in the direction of:

```
line <- read.csv (file, nrows = 1, header=FALSE)

while{

    algoritm to add the rowns -> data.frame?

    write.csv(dataframe, fileadress)

}

close(file reader)
close (file writer)
```

I know this is very basic, but I would be very glad with every tip/idea.

Answer (score 0):

In R you should read in the whole file, e.g. into the variable `tab`.

Then you can just write `tab2 <- tab[ ,-4]`.

The -4 means to drop the 4th column, the nothing infront of the comma means 'all rows'.

Then write the whole table to a file.

Note that it is the preferred way to do something like this in R. Loops are only used when really needed.

(You might also want to look at read.table instead of read.csv)

UPDATE:

As GregF notes this is incomplete. I wanted to del this answer but then saw that he had del'ed his too. So please see his comment for what needs to be done to have the repetitions you want.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see this. This glosses over the fact that the OP wants to repeat the number of rows in the dataset. To do this, the following code should work (assuming you've already loaded the dataset:
`tab2 <- tab[rep(1:nrow(df), df$Amount),-4 ]`